# What does the "[^]" regex pattern mean (javascript regex)?

Tags: javascript, python, regex

While trying to use some Javascript regex pattern in a Python program, I came accross a weird `[^]` pattern (part of longer patterns like `"<[^]+(?:id=\"block[_-]commerce[_-]cart[_-]cart|class=\"commerce[_-]product[_-]field)"`).

**What does this pattern mean?** Why would one want to negate an empty character class?!

Comment: A negated or complemented character set. That is, it matches anything that is not enclosed in the brackets. You can specify a range of characters by using a hyphen. Everything that works in the normal character set also works here.

For example, [^abc] is the same as [^a-c]. They initially match 'r' in "brisket" and 'h' in "chop." Check this.. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions

Comment: `[^]` in JS will match any character including newline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In JavaScript, `[^]` means `any character`.

However, it is advised that you should be using `[\s\S]` instead.

Have a look at [regex101.com demo](https://regex101.com/r/xI5gI1/1)

In [Python](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html), it will throw an exception (`[^ Incomplete character class`), and you'd better use `.` with `re.DOTALL` (or `re.S`) flag, or the `[\s\S]` character class.

Comment: `However, it is deprecated` Who said it is deprecated? It's in the specs.

Comment: @nhahtdh: Sorry, I think I assumed it from the following message on regex101: `Note: Avoid this construct, use . or [\s\S] instead.` I updated the text.

Comment: I guess it's advised to use `[\s\S]` for readability and portability, which is a valid concern, since `[^]` and `[]` are JavaScript only constructs, and confuses the heck out of anyone who is not playing with regex.

Comment: @nhahtdh: I also think so, portability of regexps looks like a growing tendency nowadays (such questions start appearing more frequently).